# Why can not I read all the descendants of "root" ? C# HTML

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-select

How do I properly load a combobox object from an HTML page in C #?
Why can not I read all the descendants of "root" ?

```
<select name="mainCategory">
    <option value=""> select1 </option>
    <option value="21"> Antiques & Art </option>
    <option value="61"> Office and Advertising </option>
    <option value="22"> Jewelry & Watches </option>
    <option value="23"> For Kids </option>
    <option value="24"> Home & Garden </option>
    <option value="39"> Erotica </option>
    <option value="25"> Videos </option>
    <option value="26"> Company and Industry </option>
    <option value="27"> Photography </option>
    <option value="28"> Games </option>
    <option value="29"> Collections </option>
    <option value="30"> Computers </option>
    <option value="31"> Books and Comics </option>
    <option value="32"> Automotive </option>
    <option value="33"> Music and Instruments </option>
    <option value="34"> Clothing, Shoes, Accessories </option>
    <option value="40" selected="selected"> Other </option>
    <option value="81"> Crafts </option>
    <option value="35"> Consumer Electronics </option>
    <option value="36"> Sport and Tourism </option>
    <option value="37"> Phones & Accessories </option>
    <option value="38"> Health and Beauty </option>
    <option value="62"> Food </option>
</select>
```

By using such code :

```
HtmlElement root = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")[2];
```

or

```
HtmlElement root = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainCategory");
```

Element "root" contains only one child - "select1", which there are no more descendants.
Why can not I read all the descendants of "root" ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `OPTION` tags seem to be malformed. Instead of:

```
<option> value="21"> Antiques & Art </option>
```

It should be:

```
<option value="21"> Antiques & Art </option>
```

The first is correctly created, though.

While I do believe some browsers could have no issue rendering it, I don't know id the model would pass validation.

[EDIT] I posted this answer before you fixed the tags on your post. Does it work now?

Comment: That's perfectly fine. Did your code worked after you fixed it?

Comment: It works, but problem is in read all the descendants of "root".

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test right now, but can you try and check if you can access the childNodes property?

Comment: root - Children.Count = 1;    select1 - Children.Count = 0

Comment: And, just out of sheer curiosity... How many Children does this lone Child have?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I'll run some tests of my own when I have the opportunity later tonight.